# Add a static file with react-router to pass lets encrypt verification

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to install HTTPS in a gitlab pages, with a React site and react router.

Certbot is asking me to add a page with a code:

```
Make sure your web server displays the following content at
http://YOURDOMAIN.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/5TBu788fW0tQ5EOwZMdu1Gv3e9C33gxjV58hVtWTbDM
before continuing:

5TBu788fW0tQ5EOwZMdu1Gv3e9C33gxjV58hVtWTbDM.ewlbSYgvIxVOqiP1lD2zeDKWBGEZMRfO_4kJyLRP_4U

#
# output omitted
#

Press ENTER to continue
```

It's a one page site, so I don't really know where to add a static page with url: `http://YOURDOMAIN.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/5TBu788fW0tQ5EOwZMdu1Gv3e9C33gxjV58hVtWTbDM`

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Did you find and answer?

Comment: @jrSakizci yep, added as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do it with static page, but Certbot allows you to use an alternative method with DNS Challenge.

You need to put a TXT in your DNS hostzone, and then Certbot will compare it to the one he is asking you.

To get the TXT content, you must run certbot like that ( I use Docker )

```
docker run -it --rm --name certbot \                                                                                                                    
    -v "$PWD/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt" \
    -v "$PWD/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt" \
    certbot/certbot \
    certonly \
    -m email@company.com \
    --manual \
    --preferred-challenges dns-01 \
    --no-eff-email \
    --manual-public-ip-logging-ok \
    --keep-until-expiring \
    --agree-tos \
    -d mydomain.com \
    --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
```

Just change your email, and the domain you want to work with.

More details [in gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/lets_encrypt_for_gitlab_pages.html).

Hope it helps

Comment: I've been struggling with this for days. So you don't put the challenge code in the backend?

Comment: I'm using Heroku, but I feel like your answer might help. But it's not clear what it means to "to put a TXT in your DNS hostzone"